# How do I use the backgroundworker with MVVM on startup without binding the command to a button?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

The approch of my little WPF App is first to copy x files and the user shall see this on the progressbar.
I only find ways to do it with a button which command is binded to the VM.
Isn't there any possible way to call this all on startup without the use of a button?

Edit:

This is an example how I tried:

```
   public ViewModelDfsync()
    {
        this.instigateWorkCommand =
                new RelayCommand(o => this.worker.RunWorkerAsync(),
                                    o => !this.worker.IsBusy);

        this.worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        this.worker.DoWork += this.DoWork;
        this.worker.ProgressChanged += this.ProgressChanged;
    }


    private readonly BackgroundWorker worker;
    private readonly RelayCommand instigateWorkCommand;

    // your UI binds to this command in order to kick off the work
    public RelayCommand InstigateWorkCommand
    {
        get { return this.instigateWorkCommand; }
    }

    private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // do time-consuming work here, calling ReportProgress as and when you can
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\files");
        var destDir = @"C:\files\newDir";
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            FileInfo fileName = new FileInfo(file);
            FileInfo destFile = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(destDir, fileName.Name));
            if (destFile.Exists)
            {
                if (fileName.LastWriteTime > destFile.LastWriteTime)
                {
                    fileName.CopyTo(destFile.FullName, true);
                    worker.ReportProgress(CurrentProgress);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                fileName.CopyTo(destFile.FullName);
                worker.ReportProgress(CurrentProgress);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.CurrentProgress = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }


    private int currentProgress;
    public int CurrentProgress
    {
        get => currentProgress;
        private set
        {
            if (currentProgress != value)
            {
                currentProgress = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentProgress");
            }
        }
    }
```

this is my progressbar in xaml:

```
<ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding CurrentProgress, Mode=OneWay}" Height="20"/>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your setup and show us what you've already tried. Also, please read the [ask] topics to get informed how to ask a well-received and answerable question.

Comment: Do you need to stick with the backgroundworker? I'd recommend binding visibility and displaydata to a VM and start an async Task with "IProgress" from Loaded event.

Comment: you can use the `interactivity` namespace to bind the command to the load event. or you can initiate the worker from VM ctor

Comment: You can have a look at an [example project](https://github.com/SirRufo/WpfWithSplash). It is an WPF app with a splash screen showing the initialization progress of some services and everything is **async**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call a command of the view model once the view/window has been loaded, either programmatically:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var vm = DataContext as ViewModel;
        vm.YourCommand.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

...or by using an interaction trigger in XAML: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/30/handling-events-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application/

```
<Window x:Class="Mm.HandlingEventsMVVM.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded" >
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding YourCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Window>
```

Neither approach breaks the MVVM pattern - both invoke a command of the view model from the view.

Comment: The interaction trigger sounds very helpful. I'll try this soon. Thanks!

Comment: You may also handle the Loaded event in the view. This solution is a bit more flexible, especially if your view may be loaded more than once for some reason.